# Symbology transfer from QGIS to ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, symbology, style

I am working with QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 simultaneously.

Is there any way to transfer my symbologies and styles from QGIS to ArcGIS Desktop?

I could not find a way to do it so far.